Finding duplicate values in an array single cell formula
Hi I have a long array with case numbers that look like this
123456
123456
123456
135790
856874
154670
154670

These array are drawn from a table with a formula and are found using the formula FindNumber which I've defined in the name manager
I want to be able to look at this array (which is wholly located in cell B2) and return the following array
123456 
154670

as the elements in the array that have duplicate values
I can do this if I separate it into three parts, with the first part being the formula that gets the array, the second in the next column over being the following formula
=N(COUNTIF($B$2#, $B2)>1)

copied down the length of the original array, generating a list of numbers based on hoow many times the original values are located in the array and finishing it off with the formula
= unique(filter(A2#, B2:B267=1))

But I am essentially running into the constraints of excel doing calculations within formulas.
I've tried to do step 2 through something along the lines of
= countif(FindNumber, index(FindNumber, 1))

To at least try to find it for the first number, with maybe being able to copy it down, but I have hit a wall. I am not looking for a VBA solution.

Try: =LET(a,B2#,UNIQUE(FILTER(a,MMULT(N(a=TOROW(a,3)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(a))^0)>1)))

Or: if there are line feeds then =LET(a,B2,b,TEXTSPLIT(a,,CHAR(10)), UNIQUE(FILTER(b,MMULT(N(b=TOROW(b,3)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(b))^0)>1)))

Do you mean the array is concatenated as text in B2 or the spilling formula is located in B2 and spills down? It may be more interesting to share the formula used to create your array, since we could get the end result at once rather than using the calculated array as a starting point.

@MarkS. The values I want from the original array are only the ones that have duplicate values in the array

=unique(filter(b2#,countifs(b2#,b2#)>1))

May be this is what you're trying to get:
=FILTER(B2#,DROP(FREQUENCY(B2#,B2#),-1)>1)

Count unique values among duplicates - Microsoft Support

Use TEXTSPLIT to split on the carriage return then get a unique list and iterate that checking if it exist more than once.  Then Join it back together.
=LET(
    t,TEXTSPLIT(B2,,CHAR(10)),
    unq,UNIQUE(t),
    TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,REDUCE("",unq,LAMBDA(z,y,IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(t=y))>1,VSTACK(z,y),z)))))


if by which is wholly located in cell B2 means it is a spillable formula in B2 and not all the values in B2 then we can simplify the formula:
=LET(
    t,B2#,
    unq,UNIQUE(t),
    REDUCE(,unq,LAMBDA(z,y,IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(t=y))>1,VSTACK(z,y),z))))



=UNIQUE(FILTER(B2#, COUNTIFS(B2#, B2#) > 1))


